# How do I interpret significant results in meta-regression?

Tags: interpretation, meta-analysis, meta-regression

```
                         estimate      se     tval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
intrcpt                     0.6952  0.0796   8.7313  <.0001   0.5232   0.8672  *** 
participantsyounger kids   -0.4279  0.1501  -2.8513  0.0136  -0.7521  -0.1037    * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I ran a meta regression for my meta-analysis. I divided the participants into younger kids and older kids and the results showed that both groups are significant as the p-value is less than 0.05. How should I report this data?

If I understood it correctly, the `intrcpt` value is for the older kids group. Is this correct?

Comment: If you specified it as you claim, then yes, the intercept is the base value for the older kids. For the younger kids the estimate is `intrcpt + participantsyounger kids`.

Comment: My interpretation is simply that you estimates correctly and beyond random variability the effect of your study (I guess a treatment) in older subjects... This is what the intercept tells you...

Comment: @user2974951Thank you for your reply! How about the p-value in older kids group? Where can I find this information? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you coded older and younger kids as a factor, lm automatically created dummy variables. The first level of your factor is older kids, this is your reference level, and is estimated in the intercept term `intrcpt`, which is equal to `0.6952`.

The effect of the younger kids (the second level) is estimated in the `participantsyounger kids` term, however, this is estimated as the difference from the reference level. To get the estimate of the younger kids you do `intrcpt + participantsyounger kids`.

Comment: Thank you! How about the p-value in the older kids group? Where can I find this information?

Comment: @M.L The p-values do not need to be added, they are in the right place already, so the p-value for the older kids is `<.0001` while for the younger it is `0.0136`.

Comment: Thank you! So does it mean that both groups are statistically significant?

Comment: @M.L Yes, the older kids estimate is significantly different from zero, while the younger kids are significantly different from the older kids.

Comment: Thanks! So the p-value for younger kids here is not the p-value across studies; instead, it is the comparison with the intrcpt group, is it correct?

Comment: @M.L Yes, it is the comparison of younger vs. older kids, and it is telling you that the younger kids are different from the older kids. The intercept does not represent all levels.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you please recommend some articles for this topic? I am new to meta-regression and would like to learn more about this.

Comment: @M.L Any introductory textbook on linear models will do. http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/books/LinearModelsWithR.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, I have one last question, if the mix effects model moderator test shows that the p-value is bigger than 0.05, does it still make sense to use this model?